# Merging DEM elevation attributes with streets shapefile

Tags: qgis, dem, merge, elevation, streets

I have a DEM and a separate shapefile of all the roads within the bounds of the DEM. I want to combine the elevation data with the road data so that I can have the roads displayed with a graduated color symbiology based on the elevation of the road at any given point. Essentially a road map where the roads in the valleys are dark red and the roads on the summits are near-white, with a gradation for everything in between. Is this possible in QGIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Split the roads into short segments, I use 20 m
2. Drape to set Z of each road vertice from your DEM
3. Symbolize your layer with graduated symbol, using the z values, for example with `z_min($geometry)`

[image]